# Ruby on Rails: Page Redirect Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble with a page `redirect` issue in a small multi-step form process within a `Rails` application. Here's the rundown,

1.) There are 3 pages to this form with a, "**save**" and "**next**", button at the bottom of each page.

2.) If a user has filled out new information on the page, and attempts to click the next button, a warning modal popups and prompts the user to save their changes, or discard. This is where my issue is occurring.

3.) Instead of directing the user to the next page as they intended after pressing the modal save button, it instead just refreshes the same page the user is currently on.

I've tried everything, but honestly am not very experienced with Rails. I have made a collection on codepen for you to see all of the files.

[Rails Files](http://codepen.io/collection/njzvpo/)

```
Quick breakdown of the three files you will see.
```

1.) The saveModal is the popup that prompts for save or discard.

2.) Skills is just one of the 3 pages in the form. Any important info for you here would be at the top and bottom of the document I assume.

3.) The controller code where I think the redirect is happening is also there.

Comment: you can use `= link_to` instead of button

Comment: I don't really think that solves the problem though. The controller is doing something that causes that behavior to occur. Since I am unfamiliar with Rails, I do not want to just remove all of that stuff, since I am not really sure what it is doing.